# Two DialogFragment get overlaid

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to show two `DialogFragment` at the same time. One of them is a full-screen dialog, the second should be visible after the user dismisses the full-screen one.

This is what I'm trying to achieve (`DialogFragment #1` -> `DialogFragment #2` -> `Fragment`):

[image: Expected behaviour]

The problem is:

1. `DialogFragment #1` is initiated at the same time than `Fragment`.
2. `Fragment` performs a network call that will show the
   `DialogFragment #2` once finishes.
3. `DialogFragment #2` appears over the `DialogFragment #1` while it should be shown under it.

So it looks like this:

[image: Current behaviour]

Would it be possible to change the elevation of a DialogFragment or any way to force one to appear over the other?

Comment: Nice explanation BTW . I don't think that's possible because there is no stack which we can manipulate like the Activity Stack.  try hiding `DialogFragment#1` first before opening `DialogFragment#2` and just after that show `DialogFragment#1`  . have you tried that ? you can persist the data which `DialogFragment#1` showing in a VM easily if thats the case .

Comment: Maybe, after DialogFragment2 was created you should get the common fragmentManager in it. Find the DialogFrament1 in the backstack, remove it from the backstack, add it above the DialogFragment1 and commit